# Some textures are not displayed and game crashes without error

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

The engine constantly gives out messages:

```
02-28 15:22:53.029: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:54.769: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool$1<Vector2> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:55.129: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.util.TransformationPool$1<Transformation> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:58.849: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool$1<Vector2> was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:58.959: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool$1<Vector2> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:59.169: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool$1<Vector2> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
02-28 15:22:59.369: I/AndEngine(946): org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool$1<Vector2> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
```

Sometimes, when new level of my game is loaded, some textures are not displayed and game crashes without error in LogCat. 
Anybody know any reasons why so occurs?